# How To Set Diagram Builder Property

Tags: yui3, alloy-ui

I'm using `alloy-ui Diagram Builder`, I want to set Diagram Builder Property value when other Properties is set or change.

I have problem when name property is set or change other property is set for a new value but the table don't refresh.
So it must click the node again for refreshing the property table.

How I can refreshing the property table?

This is my `Attr` Setting for setting the new value:

```
duration: {
             setter: function(val) {
                   var instance = this;
                   var newVal = getBrackets( this.get("name") );
                   newVal = defaultDuration[newVal];
                   if( newVal == "" || newVal == null) newVal = 0;

                   if( val == "" || newVal != val ){
                       return newVal;
                   } 
                   else{
                       return val;
                   }                                
             }
          }
```

Comment: Please post more information about what you are trying to do. And post the **shortest** amount of code that produces your unexpected result. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you stiemannkj1 for your advice

Comment: Cross posted in [the Liferay AlloyUI forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/58174972).

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `durationChange` event on the `DiagramBuilder` in order to execute code when the value of the `duration` attribute changes.

You can do this using the [`DiagramBuilder.on()` Method](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DiagramBuilder.html#method_on):

```
diagramBuilder.on('durationChange', function(event) {
    // your code here...
});
```

**OR** the [`DiagramBuilder.after()` Method](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DiagramBuilder.html#method_after):

```
diagramBuilder.after('durationChange', function(event) {
    // your code here...
});
```